# Uploading multiple large json files in one go React-native to NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, multer

I am trying to upload multiple large size JSON files from React-native to node js.

The files are being uploaded unless the file in larger in size, in which case, it does not upload in one try.

I suspect that:
**Since the upload code is in a for loop the code is starting the upload but not waiting for the file to upload and starting to upload the next file**

Is there any way to ensure that each file gets uploaded in one go?

```
syncFunction() {
  var RNFS = require('react-native-fs');
  var path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/toBeSynced';
  RNFS.readDir(path)
  .then((success) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < success.length; i++) {
      var fileName = success[i].name
      var filePath = success[i].path
      var uploadUrl = 'http://192.168.1.15:3333/SurveyJsonFiles/GetFiles/'

      if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        filePath = filePath.replace("file://", "")
      } else if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        filePath = filePath
      }
      const data = new FormData();
      data.append("files", {
        uri: filePath,
        type: 'multipart/form-data',
        name: fileName,
      });

      const config = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
        },
        body: data,
      };

      fetch(uploadUrl, config)
      .then((checkStatusAndGetJSONResponse) => {
        console.log(checkStatusAndGetJSONResponse);
        this.moveFile(filePath, fileName)
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      });
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.message);
  });
}
```

The JSON files will more than 50Mb depending on data, since it contains base64 image data the size will increase as the user takes more photos.

The app will be creating new files when the user records any information, There is no error message displayed for partial file upload.

The this.moveSyncedFiles() is moving the synced files to another folder so that the same file does not get uploaded multiple times

```
 moveFile(oldpath, oldName) {
  var syncedPath = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/syncedFiles'
  RNFS.mkdir(syncedPath)
  syncedPath = syncedPath + "/" + oldName
  RNFS.moveFile(oldpath, syncedPath)
    .then((success) => {
      console.log("files moved successfully")
      })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err.message)
      });
    }
```

Comment: Can you give more specific information about what happens? What size are the JSON files, how many are there in the toBeSynced folder, and is there an error message? What is this.moveSyncedFiles doing, I'm guessing that is the function that is supposed to be uploading

Comment: @LiamMacDonald Explanation added in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the fault was on the nodejs side and nodemon was restarting the server every time a new file was found so we just moved the uploads folder outside the scope of the project